# Choice Field with Radio button not appearing on the admin panel

Tags: python, html, django, url, view

This is my passsenger model. When I go to my default django model, I can see every fields but not the choice field. I want the option to select the gender of the patient. ALso, I want this in my form. But, there is no field name Gender in my admin panel in the first place. What is the issue??

```
class Passenger(models.Model):
    # book_id = models.OneToOneField(Booking, on_delete = models.CASCADE, primary_key = True)
    First_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    Last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    Nationality = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    Passport_No = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    Passport_Exp_Date = models.DateField(blank=False)
    Contact_Number = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    Email = models.EmailField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    Customer_id = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    CHOICES = [('M', 'Male'), ('F', 'Female'), ('O', 'Others')]
    Gender = forms.ChoiceField(label='Gender', widget= forms.RadioSelect(choices=CHOICES))
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a `ModelForm` and use it to override [`ModelAdmin.form`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.form) for showing radio buttons in admin site, like this:

```
# models.py
class Passenger(models.Model):
   # rest of the fields
   CHOICES = [('M', 'Male'), ('F', 'Female'), ('O', 'Others')]
   Gender = models.CharField(max_length=50,choices=CHOICES)  # field name should be gender(all lowercase)

# admin.py
class PassengerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Passenger
        fields = '__all__'

    Gender = froms.ChoiceField(
        label = 'Gender',
        choices = [('M', 'Male'), ('F', 'Female'), ('O', 'Others')]
        initial = 'M',
        widget = forms.RadioSelect,
    )

class PassengerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     form = PassengerForm
 
admin.site.register(Passenger, PassengerAdmin)
```

FYI: As per [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) standard, attribute names should be `snake_case`.

### Update

Try like this using [`radio_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.radio_fields):

```
class PassengerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     radio_fields = {"Gender": admin.VERTICAL}
 
admin.site.register(Passenger, PassengerAdmin)
```

Comment: Error comes up in the passenger Model because, CHOICES are not defined...can you help??

Comment: where should i put this ?? in which py??                                                               
  class PassengerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     form = PassengerForm
 also this??
admin.site.register(Passenger, PassengerAdmin)

Comment: they should be in admin.py file. Please see the updated answer

Comment: admin.site.register(Passenger, PassengerAdmin) when i do this, it says passenger is already registered, and when i remove Passenger , another error comes" TypeError: 'MediaDefiningClass' object is not iterable". Please help!!

Comment: if you previously have `admin.site.register(Passenger)` or `@admin.register(Passenger)`, remove them, then add `admin.site.register(Passenger, PassengerAdmin)
`. Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-objects

Comment: I did that according to you. The error were removed. BUt in admin panel, gender field is char field and also on the form, it shows charfield. I need the radio button. Please help!!

Comment: can you help me putting the radio button appear on the form? It apperas as a dropdown. can you help me?

Comment: the radio button doesnt appear anywhere..neither in admin panel nor in form...Only dropdown appears as choice both in admin and in form on the frontend...Can you help me ruddra??

Comment: Are you using `admin.site.register(Passenger, PassengerAdmin)`?

Comment: yes i did. Ok, if the radio button doesnt appear inside the admin panel..i need it to appear in the form...but its dropdown function only...no radio button on the form.